# Clojure Time Series Analysis

Tags: performance, clojure

I have a large data set (200GB uncompressed, 9GB compressed in bz2 -9 ) of stock tick data.

I want to run some basic time series analysis on them.

My machine has 16GB of RAM.

I would prefer to:

- keep all data, compressed, in memory
- decompress that data on the fly, and stream it [so nothing ever hits disk]
- do all analysis in memory

Now, I think there's nice interactions here with Clojure's laziness, and future objects (i.e. I can define objects s.t. when I try to access them, I'll decompress them on the fly.)

Question: what are the things I should keep in mind when doing high performance time series analysis in Clojure?

I'm particular interested in tricks involving:

- efficiently storing tick data in memory
- efficiently doing computation
- weird convolutions to reduce # of passes over the data

Books / articles / research paper suggestions welcome. (I'm a CS PhD student).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- In terms of storing the compressed data, I don't think you will be able to do much better than your OS's own file system caching. Just make sure it s configured to use 11GB+ of RAM for file system caching and it should pull your whole compressed data set into memory as it is read the first time.
- You should then be able to define your Clojure code to pull into the data lazily via a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), which will perform the decompression for you.
- If you need to perform a second pass on the data, just create a new ZipInputStream on the same file. OS level caching should ensure that you don't hit the disk again.

Comment: GZIPInputStream/GZIPOutpuStream would be more appropriate.

Comment: There's BZip2 handling functionalitity in apache commons compress http://commons.apache.org/compress/

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of systems like that implemented in Java. It is possible. You'll certainly want to understand how to create your own lazy sequences in order to accomplish this. I also wouldn't hesitate to drop down into Java if you need to make sure that you're dealing with the primitive types that you want to deal with. e.g. Clojure won't generate code to do math on 32-bit ints, it will only generate code to work with longs, and if you don't want that it could be a pain.

It would also be worth some effort to make your in-memory format compatible with a disk format. That would give you the option of memory mapping files, or (at the very least) make your startup easy if your program were to crash. e.g. It could just read the files on disk to recover its previous state.

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question: how does Java work with memory mapped files? It seems like "mapping memory structures" and "memory safety" conflict.

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29  It was added in Java 1.4, so its been in the JDK for about 10 years or so now. :)